# Preventing unwanted animations in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I am attempting to animate the height of my `UITableView` in a smooth manner. That's working fine, however there is a bizarre side effect I am having trouble eliminating and that is as new cells are shown in the table view while it is expanding, those cells are animating their "construction". For example, some of the labels appear to "slide in" from an edge of the cell.

This is completely undesired and looks horrible. This has been a recurring problem for me and I'd like to know what the proper solution is for dealing with this.

I've tried encapsulating various things in `[UIView performWithoutAnimation:]`, but it's never obvious where or at what point I should be wrapping things in this, and it seems to only fix *some* of the animations, not all of them.

Is there an accepted best practice for preventing unwanted animations in iOS?

Comment: It would help if you would show some code of what you are doing. If the height of the table view changes because you insert a new row, then you should let insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: do its thing, and not add your own animation.

Comment: I'm not changing the rows at all, the view is resizing with a gesture.